# Generic way to link to classes/objects

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

I'd like to write a generic extension method to link two classes/objects

Classes:

```
public class Model1
{
    public Guid Model2ID { get; set; }
    public Model2 Model2 { get; set; }

    // .. other insignificant properties to this question
}

public class Model2
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to write a method that looks something like:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static Void LinkTo<T,U>(
        this T m1,
        IEnumerable<U> m2,
        m1p // expression to select what property on m1 is populated
        Action<bool,T,IEnumerable<U>> expression)
    {
        // not sure about this part at all

        m1p = u2.FirstOrDefault(expression);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var listOfModel2 = //....

Model1.LinkTo(listOfModel2, m => m.Model2, (m1,m2) m1.Model2Id == m2.ID);
```

Comment: I've removed all your comments about MVC, as that framework is not relevant to your question.

Comment: My mistake, phrased question badly - Model 1 and Model 2 come from completely separate data sources. The only thing linking them is a Guid ID. I probably shouldn't have mentioned JSON - it's just coincidental that some of the data sources are available as such.

Comment: Oh are you trying to create a generic function that will do the work for all models?

Comment: Exactly so, yeah, so I can store the linking data in each model, then just have the controller use it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you say this wasn't relevant to ASP.NET MVC? I had assumed there might be a standard or recommended way of approaching model linking for the framework. (I get now why it's not relevant to MVC, as either doing it through the model or controller could be valid)

Comment: MVC is not about linking models.  It's simply Model (Data), Controller (Logic), View (Presentation).  If this was webforms, wpf or even winforms the question and answer would be exactly the same.  You want to link two models, that is logic, it belongs where ever logic should be (in MVC thats not the model and not the view).

Comment: Ahhh, right, I see where our different view of this is coming from now - logic for me involves boolean choices, processing of data. To my eye, this doesn't - the Guids provide a one to one mapping of object to object, so I see it as those linkages being part of the data. I completely agree the controller should be actually running through it all and linking it though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70408/discussion-between-erik-philips-and-octopoid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we had discussed in Chat, I'd recommend a light-weight version of EF Context (with reflection).  This is completely custom and dynamic, you simply need to use `KeyAttribute` and `ForeignKeyAttribute` on your models and add the models to your this custom `Context`.  I only wired up the Add, as the rest you should be able to figure out on your own.

Classes:

```
public class Staff
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("Contact")]
    public Guid ContactId { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("Dog")]
    public Guid DogId { get; set; }
    public Dog Dog { get; set; }
}

public class Dog
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Context:

```
public class Context
{
    //Add as many of these as you want.  Don't forget to make public properties for them!
    private ObservableCollection<Staff> _staffs = new ObservableCollection<Staff>();
    private ObservableCollection<Contact> _contacts = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();
    private ObservableCollection<Dog> _dogs = new ObservableCollection<Dog>();
    
    
    private List<IForeignKeyRelation> _relations = new List<IForeignKeyRelation>();
    
    public Context()
    {
        var observables = this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .ToList();
        
        foreach(var observable in observables)
        {
            var notifyCollection = observable.GetValue(this) as INotifyCollectionChanged;
            if (notifyCollection != null)
            {
                notifyCollection.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged;
                Type principalType = observable.FieldType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                
                var relations = principalType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                    .ToList()
                    .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(ForeignKeyAttribute)) as ForeignKeyAttribute != null)
                    .Select(p => new { PrincipalForeignKeyInfo = p, ForeignKey = p.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(ForeignKeyAttribute)) as ForeignKeyAttribute })
                    .Where(p => principalType.GetProperty(p.ForeignKey.Name) != null)
                    .Select(p => {
                        var principalForeignKeyInfo = p.PrincipalForeignKeyInfo;
                        var principalRelationInfo = principalType.GetProperty(p.ForeignKey.Name);
                        var dependantType = principalRelationInfo.PropertyType;
                        var dependantKeyProperties = dependantType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                            .ToList()
                            .Where(dp => dp.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(KeyAttribute)) as KeyAttribute != null)
                            .ToList();
                        var dependantKeyInfo = dependantKeyProperties.FirstOrDefault();
                        
                        var isValid = (dependantKeyInfo != null)
                            // Don't allow INT to GUID comparisons
                            // Keys need to be of same type;
                            && (principalForeignKeyInfo.PropertyType == dependantKeyInfo.PropertyType);
                        
                        
                        return new {
                            IsValid = isValid,
                            PrincipalRelationInfo = principalRelationInfo,
                            DependantType = dependantType,
                            PrincipalCollection = observable.GetValue(this),
                            PrincipalForeignKeyInfo = principalForeignKeyInfo,
                            DependantKeyInfo =  dependantKeyInfo                            
                        };
                    })
                    .Where(r => r.IsValid)
                    .Select(r =>
                    {           
                        var relationType = typeof(ForeignKeyRelation<,>).MakeGenericType(principalType, r.DependantType);
                        var relation = Activator.CreateInstance(relationType) as IForeignKeyRelation;
                        relation.GetType().GetProperty("PrincipalCollection").SetValue(relation, observable.GetValue(this));
                        relation.DependantKeyInfo = r.DependantKeyInfo;
                        relation.PrincipalForeignKeyInfo = r.PrincipalForeignKeyInfo;
                        relation.PrincipalRelationInfo = r.PrincipalRelationInfo;
                        
                        return relation;
                    })
                    .ToList();
                
                _relations.AddRange(relations);
            
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Makes storing Generic types easy when the
    // Generic type doesn't exist;
    private interface IForeignKeyRelation
    {
        PropertyInfo PrincipalForeignKeyInfo { get; set; } 
        PropertyInfo PrincipalRelationInfo { get; set; }
        PropertyInfo DependantKeyInfo { get; set; }
        void Add<T>(T value);
    }
    
    // Class to hold reflected values
    // Reflection 
    private class ForeignKeyRelation<P,D> : IForeignKeyRelation
    {
        // Staff.ContactId
        public PropertyInfo PrincipalForeignKeyInfo { get; set; } 
        public Collection<P> PrincipalCollection { get; set; }
        // Staff.Contact
        public PropertyInfo PrincipalRelationInfo { get; set; }
        // Contact.Id
        public PropertyInfo DependantKeyInfo { get; set; }
        
        public void Add<T>(T value)
        {
            if (value.GetType() == typeof(D))
            {
                var dependantKey = DependantKeyInfo.GetValue(value);
                
                var principals = PrincipalCollection.Where(p => this.PrincipalForeignKeyInfo.GetValue(p).Equals(dependantKey))
                    .ToList();
                
                foreach(var principal in principals)
                {
                    PrincipalRelationInfo.SetValue(principal, value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args) 
    {
        switch (args.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                foreach(var relation in this._relations)
                {
                    foreach(var item in args.NewItems)
                    {
                        relation.Add(item);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException(args.Action.ToString());
        }
    }
    
    public IList<Staff> Staffs
    {
        get
        {
            return _staffs;
        }
    }
    public IList<Contact> Contacts
    {
        get
        {
            return _contacts;
        }
    }
    public IList<Dog> Dogs
    {
        get
        {
            return _dogs;
        }
    }
}
```

Simple example program:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var context = new Context();
    var staff = new Staff() { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };

    var contact = new Contact();
    contact.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    contact.Name = "Hello DotFiddle!";

    staff.ContactId = contact.Id;

    context.Staffs.Add(staff);
    
    Console.WriteLine("staff contact is null: " + (staff.Contact == null).ToString());
    
    context.Contacts.Add(contact);

    Console.WriteLine("staff contact is null: " + (staff.Contact == null).ToString());
    
    Console.WriteLine("Staff.Contact.Name: "+ staff.Contact.Name);
}
```

result:

> staff contact is null: True
>
> staff contact is null: False
>
> Staff.Contact.Name: Hello DotFiddle!

[This Entire Example on DotNetFiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/r0YdeN)

Comment: That links them indeed - my problem is that I have a LOT of complicated linkages, and I'd prefer to store that data in the model itself, and have the controller automatically link everything based on it. This seems more correct to me, as it stops the controller from containing model *data* - instead it just controls the models. It also makes it much easier to see how a single model links to another.

Comment: This is becoming some what of a religous question.  Some people prefer that Controllers (logic) in MVC write up all the models which have no logic and are more [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) as necessary.  Others perfer models to be fully encapsulated.  For me it depends on who consumes the object. I tend to always use DTOs and pass them to the DataLayer to created Domain Objects.  (this doesn't really help answer the question).

Comment: Good to know - I'm not entirely familiar with MVC best practice for some of these things, and it's looking like I might have picked up a thing or two as "right" which is more "up for debate". I'll update the question to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you're going for, but one of these accomplishes it: The bottom two are 'iffy' as you can see by all the if statements. Simply put there's no way for the compiler to be able to be sure that they'll work, since you can easily pass a bad propertyExpression.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var guids = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
        var m2s = guids.Select(g => new Model2 { ID = g }).ToList();
        var model1 = new Model1 { Model2ID = m2s[4].ID };
        model1.LinkTo(m2s, (m1, m2) => m1.Model2 = m2, (m1, m2) => m2.ID == m1.Model2ID);

        var model1a = new Model1 { Model2ID = m2s[4].ID };
        model1a.LinkTo(m2s, m1 => m1.Model2, m1 => m1.Model2ID, m2 => m2.ID);

        var model1b = new Model1 { Model2ID = m2s[4].ID };
        model1b.LinkTo(m2s, m1 => m1.Model2, (m1, m2) => m1.Model2ID == m2.ID);
    }
}

public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static void LinkTo<T, U>(this T m1, IEnumerable<U> m2s, Action<T, U> action, Func<T, U, bool> filter)
    {
        if (m2s.Any(m2 => filter(m1, m2)))
        {
            var x = m2s.First(m2 => filter(m1, m2));
            action(m1, x);
        }
    }

    public static void LinkTo<T, U>(this T m1, IEnumerable<U> m2s, Expression<Func<T, U>> propertyExpression, Func<T, U, bool> filter)
    {
        var results = m2s.Where(m2 => filter(m1, m2));

        if (!results.Any())
            return;

        var x = results.FirstOrDefault();

        if (x != null)
        {
            var me = (propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression);
            if (me != null)
            {
                var pi = me.Member as PropertyInfo;
                if (pi != null)
                {
                    var setter = pi.GetSetMethod();
                    if (setter != null)
                    {
                        setter.Invoke(m1, new object[] { x });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void LinkTo<T, U, Key>(this T m1, IEnumerable<U> m2s, Expression<Func<T, U>> propertyExpression, Func<T, Key> tKey, Func<U, Key> uKey)
    {
        var results = Enumerable.Repeat(m1, 1)
            .Join(m2s, tKey, uKey, (t, u) => u);

        if(!results.Any())
            return;

        var x = results
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (x != null)
        {
            var me = (propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression);
            if (me != null)
            {
                var pi = me.Member as PropertyInfo;
                if (pi != null)
                {
                    var setter = pi.GetSetMethod();
                    if (setter != null)
                    {
                        setter.Invoke(m1, new object[] { x });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read about extension methods. They are called "from" object.
For example you can write generic extension method as below

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listOfModel2 = new Model1();

        //You can call it from "object"
        listOfModel2.MyExtensionMethod();

        //Or directly as it is declared
        ObjectExtensions.MyExtensionMethod(listOfModel2);
    }
}

public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static void MyExtensionMethod<T>(this T t)
    {
        //Do somthing
    }
}
```